# How to remove Mui Typography default classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a Typography element. I saw that it added a couple of default MUI CSS classes when debugging in the browser. So I tried to disable them by creating empty arrays at the end of the sx prop. It had no effect

As shown in the picture I want to disable those 2 classes or atleast respect the properties I have. It manages to override my properties with its properties like margin.

[image]

```html
<Typography
  variant="h1"
  sx={{
      width: '100px',
      height: '55px',
      fontSize: '20px',
      fontWeight: 500,
      lineHeight: '1.2',
      WebkitLineClamp: 4,
      WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
      marginTop: '11px',
      '& .MuiTypography-h1': {},
      '& .MuiTypography-root': {},
  }}
>
  Title
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StylesProvider` component that lets you change how styles are applied to child components. The options will be available in all child elements of the `StylesProvider`.
We can use the `injectFirst` boolean prop to add styles that override existing Material UI styles. This way, styles referenced from external CSS files will override Material UI’s.

```
import React from "react";
import StylesProvider from "@mui/styles/StylesProvider/StylesProvider";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography/Typography";
import "./styles.css";

export default function CustomTypography() {
  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <div className="App">
        <Typography>Title</Typography>
      </div>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
}
```

In `styles.css`, you can add custom css like this:

```
.MuiTypography-h1 {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.MuiTypography-root {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a global solution than  for a specific Typography element which is what I am looking for.

Comment: This is the root of your problem though. As it is right now, you have 2 css selectors with the same specificity, and the MUI style is being applied instead of yours. Unless you change how their styles are applied (like via the StyleProvider), it means all CSS you write will have to be at a higher level of specificity in order for it to be applied. I cannot think of many situations where you'd want this.

Comment: This will override mui styles and it will use styles provieded in styles.css class. I understood that was your question.